# Creating a 'live' bus map based on dates and times in HTML

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I'm looking to create something like the image below:

[Live bus map example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYSos.jpg)

Ideally the image of the bus would move across the line as time progresses and would reach each 'destination' at particular times.

I was thinking of using the HTML5 canvas feature to do this with translations/animations on the bus and Javascript to get the Date() and times, however getting the bus to move between two points over a period of time is confusing me.

For instance, would it be possible to start the bus at point 1 at 9:00 and end at point 2 at 9:10?

If there are any other ways of tackling the problem please let me know as I can only think of using canvas at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do some jquery. I've put together this little demo for you to get you started:

http://codepen.io/nilestanner/pen/yaYjQr

I was able to calculate the left position using the difference between a end time and the current time. I have the box move 100 pixels to the right then stop. This will happen over a time span of one minute for my example.

```
var start = new Date();
var end = start.setMinutes(start.getMinutes() +1); //one minute in the future
var pixelsToMove =100;
var oneMinute = (60 * 1 * 1000);
function move(){
  var percentMoved = 1 - (end- new Date())/ oneMinute;
  $('.bus').css({left: (percentMoved * pixelsToMove), position:'absolute'});
  if(percentMoved <= 1){
      setTimeout(move,100);
  }
}
move();
```

Comment: Thanks Niles, that's a good start. Though I can't figure out how your variable 'amount' represents distance if you don't know how fast the bus is going. Also, it begs the question, how can you calculate how far the bus should have traveled between two times?

Comment: @RextheTexMex In your question you mentioned that you want to move a bus between points based on time. My solution has no idea where the real bus currently is. Rather guesses progress over time.I have changed the example to move between two points based on predetermined time spans and distances. (distance on the browser)